# Bar chart data label and bar custom css with bar background,Highchart

Tags: highcharts

I have a requirement to change my bar chart to look something like below.

[image]

Following are the requirement which needs to be full filled.

1. Rounded bar with spacing on left and right
2. Grey background
3. Data labels as shown in the image(right side on bar).

The current versions(single date, multi dates) are as below.

[image: Single Date]

[image: Multi Date]

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

1) For Rounded corners, you can use

```
series: [{
        data: [Some_Sequence_of_Data],
        borderRadiusTopLeft: 10,
        borderRadiusTopRight: 10,
        borderRadiusBottomRight: 10,
        borderRadiusBottomLeft: 10
    }]
```

2) For Background over Bar lines

```
xAxis: {
            gridLineColor: '#ebeff2',
            gridLineWidth: 10,
            tickPixelInterval: 1
        }
```

3) For dataLabel style formatting, you must write logic to find maximum value of xAxis and apply that cooridinate just like

```
this.series.chart.options.plotOptions.bar.dataLabels.x -= maxValue;
```

You can format the dataLabel by furnishing

```
plotOptions: {
            series: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    style: {
                        //Your own style
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: (1) It might be worth mentioning that it needs the round-corner plugin.
(2) Grid lines wouldn't work. Gridlines are placed between bars and not on top of bars.
(3) Does not help with anything, that is just the structure of the datalabels object. Also, to show labels in circles, `shape:'circle' has to be added to dataLabels object but not to style.

Comment: Hi, this is also possible to add new column series for your background. Here you can see an example how it can work: http://jsfiddle.net/8va9p7p9/4/

Comment: @Rahul Sharma - a generic way that can programmers seek on. Not a complete explanation.

Comment: that type of generic way is provided by the docs. no point of posting an answer for that.

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński you might want to post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

For rounded column corners you can use rounded-corners plugin. You can find information about this plugin on Highcharts site:
http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/5/Rounded-Corners

For your background you can use new column series with different color. You can use parameters from Highcharts API, like grouping, showInLegend for styling this series as background. You can find information about this parameters here:

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.bar.grouping
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.bar.enableMouseTracking
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.bar.showInLegend

You can format dataLabels of your 'background series' so it will show values for your normal series:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.bar.dataLabels.formatter

```
formatter: function() {
          var series = this.series.chart.series[1];
          return series.options.data[this.point.index];
        }
```

If you want your background columns to be in 100% width of your chart, you can set your yAxis.max to their value.

You can use dataLabels.backgroundColor, dataLabels.borderRadius, dataLabels.shape and dataLabels.style for formatting your dataLabels:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.bar.dataLabels.backgroundColor
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.bar.dataLabels.borderRadius
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.bar.dataLabels.shape
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.bar.dataLabels.style

Here you can see some simple code for making your chart:

```
  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      type: 'bar',
      marginLeft: 100,
      marginRight: 100
    },
    xAxis: {
      visible: false,
    },
    yAxis: {
      min: 0,
      max: 10,
      gridLineWidth: 0,
    },
    plotOptions: {
      bar: {
        dataLabels: {
          backgroundColor: '#000',
          shape: 'circle',
          padding: 8,
          color: 'white',
          style: {
            "textShadow": "0 0 2px black, 0 0 2px black"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    series: [{
      data: [10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
      showInLegend: false,
      animation: false,
      grouping: false,
      borderRadiusTopLeft: 7,
      borderRadiusTopRight: 7,
      borderRadiusBottomRight: 7,
      borderRadiusBottomLeft: 7,
      pointWidth: 15,
      enableMouseTracking: false,
      color: '#aaa',
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        x: 20,
        formatter: function() {
          var series = this.series.chart.series[1];
          return series.options.data[this.point.index];
        }
      }
    }, {
      name: 'normal series',
      data: [9, 7, 4, 7, 3],
      color: 'orange',
      borderRadiusBottomRight: 7,
      borderRadiusBottomLeft: 7,
      pointWidth: 15,
    }]
  });
```

Here you can see an example how it can work:
http://jsfiddle.net/8va9p7p9/4/

Kind regards.